# help inserting new row into a db using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
else
    {
        SubCategory subCat = new SubCategory
        {
            SubCategoryName = name,
            Active = false,
            CategoryID=Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue)
        };
        db.SubCategories.InsertOnSubmit(subCat);
    }

    db.SubmitChanges();
```

The following line is causing an error:

```
CategoryID=Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue)
```

I have confirmed that the SelectedValue in my DDL is an int, and that the database is expecting an int, so I don't understand why asp.net gives me a YSOD saying "Input string was not in a correct format."

If I assign CategoryID a number manually, it works.

EDIT: The problem was because I was populating the drop down list in my code behind and I didn't wrap it in a (!IsPostBack). So it was destroying the list, repopulating it and setting the index at 0 each time on post back.

Comment: Is this EntityFramwork, or Linq2Sql, or Nhibernate?

Comment: Have you tried putting a break point on it and seeing if you have a selected value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so try this then

```
else
    {
        int cat = Convert.ToInt32(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);
        SubCategory subCat = new SubCategory
        {
            SubCategoryName = name,
            Active = false,
            CategoryID = cat
        };
        db.SubCategories.InsertOnSubmit(subCat);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Where does `ddlCategory` come from? What's the value of `ddlCategory.SelectedValue`? When this gets run? Clearly it's not a valid integer-representing string at this point in time.

Comment: ddlCategory is an asp.net dropdownlist. SelectedValue is expecting a value of type String, so converting it to an int should work, just like when you use .toString() for converting other types to type string.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

`Int.Parse(ddlCategory.SelectedValue);`

Comment: that still doesn't work- even though it seems logical that it should.

Answer (score 0):

is the categoryID foreign key for another table? if yeah then try to pull the Category object and then assign it to the subCat.Category and see if it works (the relation must be set in the DBML designer)

one last thing: when exactly it throws the exception?